# Sell tokens to a contract and burn them after

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

The goal is to make a crowdsale smart contract where investors can buy tokens (no cap, no initial supply, all tokens are minted) and sell them to a contract for some price (rate in my case). And I want to burn automatically these tokens after the sale.

I used [openzeppelin library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts), here is a token:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./DetailedERC20.sol";
import "./MintableToken.sol";
import "./BurnableToken.sol";

contract myToken is DetailedERC20, MintableToken, BurnableToken {
    constructor(
        string _name, 
        string _symbol, 
        uint8 _decimals
        )
        DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, _decimals)
        public
    {

    }
}
```

The crowdsale contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import './Crowdsale.sol';
import './MintedCrowdsale.sol';
import './Ownable.sol';

contract myCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, Ownable {

    constructor(uint256 _rate, address _wallet, ERC20 _token) Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token) public {

    }

    function setRate(uint256 newRate) onlyOwner public {
        rate = newRate;
    }

}
```

Crowdsale.sol where I'm trying to implement sellTokens function (we need to transfer ether back to an investor and burn tokens):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./ERC20.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./SafeERC20.sol";
import "./BurnableToken.sol";


/**
 * @title Crowdsale
 * @dev Crowdsale is a base contract for managing a token crowdsale,
 * allowing investors to purchase tokens with ether. This contract implements
 * such functionality in its most fundamental form and can be extended to provide additional
 * functionality and/or custom behavior.
 * The external interface represents the basic interface for purchasing tokens, and conform
 * the base architecture for crowdsales. They are *not* intended to be modified / overridden.
 * The internal interface conforms the extensible and modifiable surface of crowdsales. Override
 * the methods to add functionality. Consider using 'super' where appropriate to concatenate
 * behavior.
 */
contract Crowdsale is BurnableToken {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  using SafeERC20 for ERC20;

  // The token being sold
  ERC20 public token;

  // Address where funds are collected
  address public wallet;

  // How many token units a buyer gets per wei.
  // The rate is the conversion between wei and the smallest and indivisible token unit.
  // So, if you are using a rate of 1 with a DetailedERC20 token with 3 decimals called TOK
  // 1 wei will give you 1 unit, or 0.001 TOK.
  uint256 public rate;

  // Amount of wei raised
  uint256 public weiRaised;

  /**
   * Event for token purchase logging
   * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
   * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
   * @param value weis paid for purchase
   * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
   */
  event TokenPurchase(
    address indexed purchaser,
    address indexed beneficiary,
    uint256 value,
    uint256 amount
  );

  /**
   * @param _rate Number of token units a buyer gets per wei
   * @param _wallet Address where collected funds will be forwarded to
   * @param _token Address of the token being sold
   */
  constructor(uint256 _rate, address _wallet, ERC20 _token) public {
    require(_rate > 0);
    require(_wallet != address(0));
    require(_token != address(0));

    rate = _rate;
    wallet = _wallet;
    token = _token;
  }

  // -----------------------------------------
  // Crowdsale external interface
  // -----------------------------------------

  /**
   * @dev fallback function ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
   */
  function () external payable {
    buyTokens(msg.sender);
  }

  /**
   * @dev low level token purchase ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   */
  function buyTokens(address _beneficiary) public payable {

    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
    _preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = _getTokenAmount(weiAmount);

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    _processPurchase(_beneficiary, tokens);
    emit TokenPurchase(
      msg.sender,
      _beneficiary,
      weiAmount,
      tokens
    );

    _updatePurchasingState(_beneficiary, weiAmount);

    _forwardFunds();
    _postValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
  }

  function sellTokens(uint256 amount) public {

    uint256 weiAmount = amount.mul(rate);
    address myAddress = address(this);

    require(myAddress.balance >= weiAmount);
    weiRaised = weiRaised.sub(weiAmount);

    burn(amount);

  }

  // -----------------------------------------
  // Internal interface (extensible)
  // -----------------------------------------

  /**
   * @dev Validation of an incoming purchase. Use require statements to revert state when conditions are not met. Use `super` in contracts that inherit from Crowdsale to extend their validations.
   * Example from CappedCrowdsale.sol's _preValidatePurchase method: 
   *   super._preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, _weiAmount);
   *   require(weiRaised.add(_weiAmount) <= cap);
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _preValidatePurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    require(_beneficiary != address(0));
    require(_weiAmount != 0);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Validation of an executed purchase. Observe state and use revert statements to undo rollback when valid conditions are not met.
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _postValidatePurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    // optional override
  }

  /**
   * @dev Source of tokens. Override this method to modify the way in which the crowdsale ultimately gets and sends its tokens.
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be emitted
   */
  function _deliverTokens(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _tokenAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    token.safeTransfer(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Executed when a purchase has been validated and is ready to be executed. Not necessarily emits/sends tokens.
   * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
   * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be purchased
   */
  function _processPurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _tokenAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    _deliverTokens(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Override for extensions that require an internal state to check for validity (current user contributions, etc.)
   * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _updatePurchasingState(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    // optional override
  }

  /**
   * @dev Override to extend the way in which ether is converted to tokens.
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei to be converted into tokens
   * @return Number of tokens that can be purchased with the specified _weiAmount
   */
  function _getTokenAmount(uint256 _weiAmount)
    internal view returns (uint256)
  {
    return _weiAmount.mul(rate);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Determines how ETH is stored/forwarded on purchases.
   */
  function _forwardFunds() internal {
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
  }
}
```

So, something goes wrong in this case. What the simplest way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that funds are forwarded to `wallet` so you do not have direct access to them.

One solution is to disable `_forwardFunds` so ether will remain in the crowdsale contract. You will have to add a function to withdraw funds once the crowdsale has finished.

Another approach is to forward funds to a vault like contract. And that contract will issue refunds if called from the crowdsale.